# Application of Ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

A large lake is to be formed by damming a river which holds initially 100million gallons of water. The water got contaminated with a pesticide of concentration of 35ppm (parts per million). The river continues to flow into the lake at a rate of 300gal/min. The river is only slightly contaminated with pesticide and has a concentration of 5ppm. The flow of water over the dam can be controlled and is set at 400gal/min. How long will it be before the water reaches an acceptable level of concentration equal to  15ppm? 
Please help me, all I know is that, it is flow rate problem

Comment: Perhaps you can form an equation for the level of concentration, as a function of time? I think it will be of the form
$$
f'(t) = \text{flow in} - \text{flow out}
$$

Comment: Yes I know... But I don't know how I will go about it from there.

Comment: Please I need the full solution, I have tried to solve it but to no avail.

Comment: So what have you tried? Let's start with the "flow in"-term. Apparently there is a river that flows in, its concentration is $5$ppm and flow rate is 300 gal/min. If the amount of water in the lake is $x$, how much does the contamination change due to this river, per minute?

Comment: @Matti P. I this is where the problem lies for me... How to get my flows in and flows out terms.. it is really not clear... I can solve it if those two are determined.

Comment: If you have $x$ gallons of 35 ppm water, and you add to it 300 gallons of 5ppm water, what concentration do you have at the end?

Comment: Definitely we are going to have (300+X)gallons of water with concentration of 40ppm.. am I right?? And is that the flows in ?? How about the flows out?... I am not qualified to chat with you . Pls help me out

Comment: Are you sure? When you have a high-concentration water and you add low-concentration water, the concentration decreases! You don't just sum the concentrations. If you have a gallon of 300 ppm water and another gallon og 300 ppm water and you put them together, surely you understand that the final concentration is not 600 ppm but rather 300 ppm.

Comment: It will definitely reduce!!! But then, it is still not clear to me... Help me from this uncertainty!!! Si vous plait!!!

Comment: I recommend that you look for water mixing problems (word problems), solve some and learn from those. Then, come back with a refreshed understanding of how liquid mixtures are calculated.

Comment: Ok message copied... But can you recommend good books for both water mixing problem and flow rates?

Comment: You don't necessarily need any book, you can just google something like "water mixing math problems"